# Determining order of matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

I need to determine the orders of the following matrices in the group $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Could someone provide me with a complete solution for the first matrix so that I know how to redo it with the second matrix?

Thank you in advance

Comment: All you need to do is find the first power of each matrix which equals identity. In this case, one can find an easy formula for powers of both matrices (find the first couple of powers and it should become clear).

Comment: Hint: n'th power of the first matrix will have n in (1,1) position. Take 7th power and use that elements belongs to $\mathbb{F}_7$.

Comment: @tessellation If I put the first matrix to the 7th power, I get $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 7 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, which is the same as...

Comment: @tessellation So in $\mathbb{F}_7$, the above matrix equals the identity matrix

Comment: @user43208 See the above comment. So what is the order? 7?

Comment: Yep. Your calculation shows the order divides 7. And since 7 is prime and the order is not 1...

Comment: @user43208 Then the order is 7. For the second one, the order is 3

Comment: But I’m glad you didn’t ask about $\pmatrix{1&3\\1&1}$.

Comment: @Lubin How would you proceed with such a matrix ?

Comment: EEK, my (probably inefficient) method would be to find the characteristic polynomial, and see what the order of a root of that was in $\mathbb F_{49}^\times$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer good enough for your specific question:
$$
\pmatrix{1&m\\0&1}\pmatrix{1&n\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&m+n\\0&1}\,,
$$
and
$$
\pmatrix{a&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{b&0\\0&1}=\pmatrix{ab&0\\0&1}\,.
$$
These relations are good no matter where (i.e. in what ring) the entries lie.
So the question boils down to asking the additive order of $1$ and the multiplicative order of $2$ in $\mathbb F_7^+$ and $\mathbb F_7^\times$, respectively.